# WebRTC: Works on chrome, but does not work on any other browser

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I'm building a WebRTC communication channel. I have a web page which uses the `RTCPeerConnection` API to communicate with a [Pion](https://github.com/pion/webrtc) backend. The backend is located on a mobile unit with a mobile connection out somewhere in the world, and the web page is viewable by anyone behind any corporate firewall. I am using `metered.ca` to provide STUN & TURN servers to service this setup. It works in some cases but not in others. On a local network it seems to work through any browser, but via mobile networks it only really works from Chrome on a desktop computer, and not through any mobile connection router (worked through a Teltonika RUT240, but not through hotspotting with an iPhone). It's driving me nuts.

The failure looks like it simply being unable to find a connection. ICE candidates are generated and exchanged, offers and answers are successfully received, and then, if it works, a connection happens nearly instantly, and if it doesn't, it simply does not happen and the `connectionState` goes to `failed` (on the website).

Is there a way to get a connection to a mobile unit in this fashion or am I wishing for a miracle here? The fact that it works on Chrome on Desktop is so weird to me, since it doesn't work with Firefox or Safari, or anything on mobile.